# Solr: Empty results when document is present

Tags: solr

Could you say why I have empty searching results.

Say, I have the following document in Solr:

```
{
  "srcphrase": "in case if",
  "id": "d77a6c9e463652c9",
  "_version_": 1479240921712164900
}
```

In my schema.xml:

```
<field name="id"
       type="string"
       indexed="true"
       stored="true"
       required="true"
       multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="srcphrase"
       type="text_en"
       indexed="true"
       stored="true"/>
...
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When submitting the query localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?q=srcphrase%3A%22in+case+if%22 I get empty results. Here is what analysis show:

[image]

Do you have some ideas why I have empty results for existing phrase?

Comment: is there any error message on console ?

Comment: No errors on the console. Solr returns 200 OK with the response body:

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"srcphrase:\"in case if\"",
      "_":"1410774019156",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}

Comment: try moving quotes (%22) from url.

Comment: If omit the quotes, Solr returns confusing results: "inning", "inning" "INS" ...

Comment: try using AND operator or use solr proximity search (using ~) to get accurate results.

Comment: akshayb, thanks for your help. The both queries 'srcphrase:in AND srcphrase:case AND srcphrase:if' and 'srcphrase:"in case if"~100' give empty results...

Comment: it should be like srcphrase:in AND case AND if . are you sure your results contain all three words ? try with other words because proximity search should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems now the problem is solved for me. I have already tried to re-index the documents, but after I have re-indexed the core once again, Solr starts returning the results.

query: `srcphrase:in AND srcphrase:case AND srcphrase:if`, the phrase found

query: `srcphrase:"case if in"~3`, the phrase found

query: `srcphrase:"in case if"`, the phrase found

query (as suggested by akshayb): `srcphrase:in AND case AND if`, the results are empty

**So re-indexing the documents matters** if you change the chain of filters for index analyzer.
To re-index the documents it is needed:

1. To remove all the existing documents

   ```
   curl http://{host}:{port}/solr/{collection}/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
   ```
2. To submit the documents once again, e.g.:

   ```
   java -Durl=http://{host}:{port}/solr/{collection}/update -jar /path/to/solr/post.jar my-doc.txt
   ```